# Using XmlPlexusConfiguration to import more configuration for a bean-style Maven extension

Tags: java, maven, configuration, plexus

I have a Maven extension that I've set up to be configured from a POM configuration object where

```xml
<configuration>
  <foo>...</foo>
  <bar>...</bar>
</configuration>
```

ends up calling

```
setFoo(...);
setBar(...);
```

methods.

I'd like to allow configurations to import extra configuration to allow a propose&second style of delegation, so

```xml
<configuration>
  <import>g:a:v</import>
  <bar>...</bar>
</configuration>
```

where the artifact g:a:v has a file *META-INF/my-project-name.xml* with content `<configuration><foo>...</foo></configuration>`.

I'd like the combination of the `<configuration>` with the import and that XML file to generate the same calls to setters as above.

---

Using

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurator;
import org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.PlexusConfiguration;
import org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.xml.XmlPlexusConfiguration;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder;
```

with

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-classworlds</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've written the following to try and parse configuration from an XML file and then invoke the configurator to configure my Maven extension.

```
{
  PlexusConfiguration configuration;
  try {
    configuration = loadConfiguration(
        log, cr.get(), EXTRA_CONFIGURATION_XML_RELATIVE_PATH);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new EnforcerRuleException(
        "Failed to load " + EXTRA_CONFIGURATION_XML_RELATIVE_PATH
        + " from " + artifactId, ex);
  }

  // TODO: is this right.
  // Newer versions have a MavenProject.getClassRealm() says
  // """
  // Warning: This is an internal utility method that is only public for
  // technical reasons, it is not part of the public API. In particular,
  // this method can be changed or deleted without prior notice and must
  // not be used by plugins.
  // """
  ClassRealm realm = null;

  try {
    configurator.configureComponent(configurable, configuration, realm);
  } catch (ComponentConfigurationException ex) {
    throw new EnforcerRuleException(
        "Failed to process configuration "
        + EXTRA_CONFIGURATION_XML_RELATIVE_PATH
        + " from " + artifactId,
        ex);
  }
}
```

where `configurable` is just the `Object` with setters and `configuration` is an `XmlPlexusConfiguration` loaded thus:

```
static XmlPlexusConfiguration loadConfiguration(
    Log log,
    ClassRoot cr,
    String path)
throws EnforcerRuleException, IOException {
  log.debug("Loading " + path + " from " + cr.art.getId());
  File classRootFile = cr.classRoot;
  if (classRootFile == null) {
    throw new EnforcerRuleException(
        "Cannot import configuration from unresolved artifact "
        + art.getId());
  }
  Xpp3Dom dom = cr.readRelativePath(
      path,
      new ClassRoot.IOConsumer<InputStream, Xpp3Dom>() {
        public Xpp3Dom read(InputStream is) throws IOException {
          try {
            return Xpp3DomBuilder.build(is, "UTF-8", true);
          } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Malformed XML", ex);
          } finally {
            is.close();
          }
        }
      });
  return new XmlPlexusConfiguration(dom);
}
```

I acquire the `ComponentConfigurator` via

```
  configurator = (ComponentConfigurator) helper.getComponent(
      ComponentConfigurator.class);
```

---

When I run this I get,

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException:
Component does not implement interface org.codehaus.plexus.component.MapOrientedComponent
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.MapOrientedComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(MapOrientedComponentConfigurator.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.AbstractComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(AbstractComponentConfigurator.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.AbstractComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(AbstractComponentConfigurator.java:37)
    at com.google.security.fences.ConfigurationImport.configure(ConfigurationImport.java:70)
    at com.google.security.fences.FencesMavenEnforcerRule.execute(FencesMavenEnforcerRule.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:193)
```

Is there some way to bridge MapOrientedComponents and the bean-style reflective setter invocation used to configure my extension?

Or is there a better way to turn the text of an XML file into additional configuration operations?

---

EDIT:

After a bit more digging it looks like

```
configurator = (ComponentConfigurator) helper.getComponent(
    ComponentConfigurator.class);
```

returns a `MapOrientedComponentConfigurator` when I run it via the integration-test `Verifier` causing the failure, but when I do not, it produces a different & compatible kind of configurator.

The difference, 100% repeatable, is whether I run with `-X` or not to cause the logger to produce debug trace.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the root-root cause, but I do know that

1. When running with `-X` to turn on debugging, `helper.getComponent(ComponentConfigurator.class)` returns a `BasicComponentConfigurator` and everything works fine.
2. When running without `-X`, the same call returns a `MapOrientedComponentConfigurator` which barfs since it can only configure `MapOrientedComponent`s.
3. Replacing that call with `new BasicComponentConfigurator()` works.
4. Working around dependency injection makes me feel dirty.

My best guess is that depending on whether debugging trace is requested, something is creating a component configurator in some scope and not cleaning up after itself.

---

https://github.com/mikesamuel/fences-maven-enforcer-rule/commit/7cab8d8bd873f2341acab088e5bdad9c3e35640b is the commit at which this behavior was "fixed."